# Connected App consumerKey Security Review issue

Tags: connected-apps, security-review

We have two connected apps that are part of a managed package that is up for review.  One app is used for API access to Salesforce from an external web platform, and the other is used as a CanvasApp to embed the external web platform directly into Salesforce.

Our security review failed because we didn't follow `Insecure Storage of Sensitive Data` security measures on the `consumerKey` of the Connected App.

The connected app XML had the `consumerKey` in it (where "WholeLongExposedConsumerKey" had the actual key):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contactEmail>sample@email.com</contactEmail>
    <description>test</description>
    <developerName>namespace__ConnectedApp1</developerName>
    <hasMobileDeviceProtection>false</hasMobileDeviceProtection>
    <iconUrl>https://link/to/icon.png</iconUrl>
    <label>Connected App 1</label>
    <logoUrl>https://link/to/icon.png</logoUrl>
    <oauthConfig>
        <callbackUrl>http://localhost:3000/auth/salesforce/callback?scope=api%20full%20id%20refresh_token</callbackUrl>
        <consumerKey>WholeLongExposedConsumerKey</consumerKey>
        <isAdminApproved>false</isAdminApproved>
        <scopes>Basic</scopes>
        <scopes>Api</scopes>
        <scopes>Full</scopes>
        <scopes>RefreshToken</scopes>
    </oauthConfig>
    <version>1.0</version>
</ConnectedApp>
```

...and they noted:

> In both ConnectedApp1 and ConnectedApp2, the consumerKey is stored insecurely

Questions:

1. As far as I know, you can't hide the `consumerKey` from the connected app metadata, nor can you change it (i.e. try encrypting it, etc) as it is read-only.  Could this be a potential false positive?  Our connected app settings demand the external platform to also provide the secret key, which is not exposed at all.
2. If it's not a false-positive, how would I securely store this `consumerKey` considering that I have no control over it?
3. Do I have to come onto a whole different authentication approach just to have this pass the security review?

I'm hoping (3) isn't the only option, as we already have a stable working package as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security Review team got back to us.  The `consumerKey` that's being stored in the Connected App metadata is a false-positive and they disregarded it in the re-submission.

It's worthwhile to just document that you're aware of the exposed `consumerKey` and that it's not sensitive data that needs to be hidden.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

We use Connected Apps as you describe them, but we don't actually include them in the package (they don't need to be included for a customer to be able to utilize them in my experience) and our apps passed without issue. So that might be an option - just remove them from the actual package.

But it also sounds like a false positive, because the Consumer Key isn't considered sensitive in my experience - we use it in URLs for oauth flows. so I would also suggest scheduling Office Hours with the SR team to see what they suggest, or try posting in the Security Review group in the Partner Community

Comment: Thanks!  For our Canvas App, I doubt we'd be able to leave that out of the package, since it's core to the whole package.  I'll post on the Security Review group and see what they say